# JIRA: Accidentally transitioned story reverted. But burndown chart still shows the transition

Tags: jira, transition

In JIRA, I have accidentally transitioned a Story from "In Progress" to "Done", though the issue is still under work. Realising the mistake I have dragged and dropped back the issue to "In Progress" swim lane. But when the Burndown chart is generated, it displays a vertical downward line indicating the mistake, though it is corrected. Please help to know how to remove the unintented vertical line from the chart.[image]

Comment: You probably can't, because in the reality of JIRA, there is a time point where the story was burned. In a sprint review, if there questions about it, it is easy enough to explain like you did to us (I made a mistake and corrected that as soon as I noticed).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I agree. Thank you very much.